# Safari bug renders browser useless

Tags: safari, mojave, web-browser

[Here's a video of what's going on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vw19bu54h7hpi3jYOqsDvSmZBWL2_8fG/view). I've tried to completely reset Safari by following [several methods](http://allgaierconsulting.com/techtalk/2015/3/10/reader-question-how-to-reset-safari-settings-without-opening-safari) on the web but the issue persists.

I'm on Mojave using Safari 12.1. I have no idea what this issue is and can't find anything like it on the web. Help!

Comment: Try starting Safari in safe mode by holding `Shift` when clicking on the Safari icon and holing until it starts.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) I have encountered this bug quite a few times myself. Most likely a bug in Safari/macOS. Consider filing a [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to Apple.

Comment: Nimesh if you've encountered this bug before how did you fix it?

Comment: In a similar manner, by force quitting Safari.

Comment: The only way I can close Safari now is to force quit. But the bug happens again as soon as I launch Safari. So that doesn't help.

Comment: Unlike your case, I am not stuck in an endless loop. Maybe something else is going wrong in your case.

Comment: The method as specified in the link you provided is from 2015 and may be incomplete. There are other com.apple.Safarixxxx.plist files in ~/Library/Preferences which may have some bearing on the problem. Because the pop-up window that flashes briefly is actually a dialog box that needs interaction before continuing, I suspect there is a corrupted Safari .plist file, perhaps one of the ones not specified in the method you linked to. Create a temporary new user to test if it is localized to your account, and try deleting some of the other .plist files as well which are not in the method linked.

Comment: IconDaemon, you're spot on. Logging in as a guest user,  Safari works just fine. Do you know of a site that provides a current list of .plist files?

Comment: In Finder, press Go, Hold alt, see the Library button, click on it. Scroll down to Safari folder.

Answer (score 1):

So I just ended up installing the latest Beta version of Safari. I really just need the browser to test web development anyway. Not an ideal solution but whatever works.